# How to install suds 0.4 on windows without Internet connection

Tags: python, suds

I need to install suds (and other Python modules) on a windows machine without Internet connection (use ftp to move the software to the machine). In another thread, I was advised to get the source (.gz or .zip), unzip it on the machine, then install it using the modules setup.py, e.g. `python setup.py install`. However, this method also requires Internet connection - at least in the case of suds. I get the error:

```
Download error: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed — Some packages may not be found!  
No local packages or download links found for distribute
```

I've searched high and low for a msi or exe install program for suds, but not found any.

Answer (score 4):

if you have installed "distribute", you can just unpack suds (e.g into c:\Install\Python\suds-jurko-0.4.1.jurko.4), open command window on python scripts directory (e.g. c:\Python32\Scripts) and run easy_install.exe with the unpacked directory as a parameter (e.g. easy_install.exe c:\Install\Python\suds-jurko-0.4.1.jurko.4).